# Kotlin Android KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, исключения

Всем добрый вечер. Решил написать я простенькую программку под андроид. Но вот никак не могу исправить ошибку. У меня постоянно в Logcat выскакивает такого рода ошибка `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.lado.kotlincurrencyconverter.CurrencyActivity$ItemSelectedFrom.onItemSelected`.

Она относится к этой строке `textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"`. Как мне решить эту проблему? Я пытался всячески изменить но никак не выходит, делал даже через переменные, вообще никак. В общем не могу никак изменить. Буду благодарен за помощь.

P.S Если что суть этого кода в том, что когда я нажимаю на спинер(у меня их 2) и выбираю из списка валюту то в `TextView` она должна отображаться(TextView у меня тоже 2).

Вот мой код

```
    open class CurrencyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    open var textView_msg: TextView? = null
    open var textView: TextView? = null
    open val currencyList = arrayOf("AUD","CAD","CHF","EUR","GBP","JPY","NZD","KHR","USD","CNY","THB","INR")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.currency_activty)
        setUpSpinnerData()
    }

    //This method will be invoked to setup data of the spinner views
    //to show lists of currency types for selection
    fun setUpSpinnerData() {
        textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyFrom) as TextView
        textView = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyTo) as TextView

        val spFrom: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.fromCurrency)
        spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = ItemSelectedFrom()
        val afrom: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
        spFrom.adapter = afrom

        val spTo: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.toCurrency)
        spTo.onItemSelectedListener = ItemSelectedTo()
        val ato: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
        spTo.adapter = ato

    }

    class ItemSelectedFrom: CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}

        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            //textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyFrom) as TextView
            textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"
        }
    }

    class ItemSelectedTo : CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}

        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            //textView = findViewById(R.id.setCurrencyTo) as TextView
            textView!!.text = "${currencyList[p2]}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Старайтесь избегать оператора `!!`.

Конструкция `foo!!.bar()` эквивалентна вызову на джаве `foo.bar()`, поэтому может привести к NullPointerException в случае foo == null.

Тогда как `foo?.bar()` есть то же, что и `foo == null ? null : foo.bar()`. И не приведет к указанному исключению.

Рекомендую прочитать небольшой раздел из документации про null-safety ([англ.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), [рус.](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/null-safety.html))

Answer (score 0):

Все проблема решена. Я немного изменил свой код. Но при этом прежний код остался, он за комментирован.

```
class CurrencyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var textView_msg: TextView ?= null
    var textView: TextView ?= null

    var currencyList = arrayOf("AUD","CAD","CHF","EUR","GBP","JPY","NZD","KHR","USD","CNY","THB","INR")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.currency_activty)
        setUpSpinnerData()
    }

    //This method will be invoked to setup data of the spinner views
    //to show lists of currency types for selection
    fun setUpSpinnerData() {

        val spFrom: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.fromCurrency)
        spFrom.onItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener0
        val afrom: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
        spFrom.adapter = afrom

        val spTo: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.toCurrency)
        spTo.onItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener1
        val ato: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currencyList)
        spTo.adapter = ato

    }

    var onItemSelectedListener0: OnItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.LALALALA)
            Log.e("KUKU", currencyList[position])
            textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
    }

    var onItemSelectedListener1: OnItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            textView = findViewById(R.id.NANANANA)
            textView?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}

    }

//    class ItemSelectedFrom: CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
//        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
//
//        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
//            textView_msg = findViewById(R.id.LALALALA)
//            Log.e("KUKU", currencyList[position])
//            textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
//        }
//    }
//
//    class ItemSelectedTo : CurrencyActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
//        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
//
//        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
//            textView = findViewById(R.id.NANANANA)
//            textView?.text = "${currencyList[position]}"
//        }
//    }
}
```

И вот мое объяснение почему тот код не работал.

Пример:

```
var textView_msg: TextView ?= null // инициализация

textView_msg?.text = "${currencyList[position]}" // вызывает setText если textView_msg != null
textView_msg!!.text = "${currencyList[position]}" // выкидывает exception если textView_msg == null
```

Вот в этом и вся разница из-за чего у меня программа и не работала. Главное понять когда нужно использовать `!!`, а когда в место этого нужно поставить `?.`.

Надеюсь, что кому-то это пригодится)

Comment: Нужно строить так код чтоб не приходилось использовать !!. Ведь во втором случае вы говорите что не может быть нулевого значения. А если оно всё-таки будет, то вы получите ошибку. 
А в первом случае вы говорите что может быть нулевым